# Print statement printing on two lines without new line being specified?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char buf[100];
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: unparseable line: '%s', ignored\n", argv[0], buf);

    }


}
```

I got this random bug in my code. Consider this file

```
echo 1
echo 2 
echo 3
```

If I were to do

```
$ gcc -Wall above.c
$ ./a.out file
./a.out: unparseable line: 'echo 1
', ignored
./a.out: unparseable line: 'echo 2
', ignored
./a.out: unparseable line: 'echo 3
', ignored
```

Why is the "', ignored" in it's own line? I want it to be 3 lines only not 6. Anyway to fix?

Comment: Because `fgets` retains the newline (if any). Please see [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221)

Comment: A [good `fgets` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) should be useful to read. Just about *any* tutorial or book that uses `fgets` should have told you about the issue.